# Google Calendar API v3 refresh OAuth 2.0 Token

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I am trying to synchronize **FullCalendar.js** with Google Calendar. My example works, but after a while (maybe 1 hour) i get this error :

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Invalid Credentials",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "authError",
                "location": "Authorization",
                "locationType": "header"
            }
        ],
        "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
    }
}
```

My token:

```
{"access_token":"ya29_MY_SECRET_TOKEN_HERE_VQ2g0165","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3599,"scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"}
```

I searched on Google API official documentation, but i did not found any clue that might help me.

How do i refresh the key? I don't want to authorize in every time.

Btw, what `"expires_in":3599` means? If token expires in 60 minutes ... how do i make it at least 1 day?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the code that you're using that is showing the error? Have you tried using a Refresh token? https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/first-call/refresh-token

Comment: Even if i use refresh token, if you close the browser for 1 hour, you can't refresh it anymore. I have found a full-backend solution in PHP, but i wasted time a lot. I wonder if this can be done only using front-end.

Comment: what is your php based solution please share what package you are using